# Tensorflow federated : How to map the remote-worker with remote datasets in iterative_process.next?

Tags: tensorflow-federated

I would like to point the federated_train_data to remote client data as shown in the code below.Is this possible? How ?

If not what further implementation is required for me to try this out. Kindly point me to the relevant code.

```
factory = tff.framework.create_executor_factory(make_remote_executor)
context = tff.framework.ExecutionContext(factory)
tff.framework.set_default_context(context)

state = iterative_process.initialize()

state, metrics = iterative_process.next(state, federated_train_data)
```

```
def make_remote_executor(inferred_cardinalities):
  """Make remote executor."""

  def create_worker_stack(ex):
    ex = tff.framework.ThreadDelegatingExecutor(ex)
    return tff.framework.ReferenceResolvingExecutor(ex)

  client_ex = []
  num_clients = inferred_cardinalities.get(tff.CLIENTS, None)
  if num_clients:
    print('Inferred that there are {} clients'.format(num_clients))
  else:
    print('No CLIENTS placement provided')

  for _ in range(num_clients or 0):
    channel = grpc.insecure_channel('{}:{}'.format(FLAGS.host, FLAGS.port))
    remote_ex = tff.framework.RemoteExecutor(channel, rpc_mode='STREAMING')
    worker_stack = create_worker_stack(remote_ex)
    client_ex.append(worker_stack)

  federating_strategy_factory = tff.framework.FederatedResolvingStrategy.factory(
      {
          tff.SERVER: create_worker_stack(tff.framework.EagerTFExecutor()),
          tff.CLIENTS: client_ex,
      })
  unplaced_ex = create_worker_stack(tff.framework.EagerTFExecutor())
  federating_ex = tff.framework.FederatingExecutor(federating_strategy_factory,
                                                   unplaced_ex)
  return tff.framework.ReferenceResolvingExecutor(federating_ex)
```

This is from https://github.com/tensorflow/federated/blob/master/tensorflow_federated/python/examples/remote_execution/remote_executor_example.py

Comment: Could you split into separate two questions? This will improve the discoverability of the answers and help the community.

Comment: Thanks @ZacharyGarrett - I have edited this question and posted the second question seperately.

Comment: Depend on what `make_remote_executor` does, this seems like it should work. Maybe the question can be extended to show the logic behind `make_remote_executor` as well as the error messages that are returned when running the code above?

Comment: @ZacharyGarrett: I have extended the question. I don't know how to point federated_train_data ->to the remote dataset on the client.

Could you help me understand what happens in the make_remote_executor() and how I can modify the logic in the method to make it point to a remote dataset.

Answer (score 2):

In the linked example, you can see that the client data is coming from a `tf.data.Dataset` per-client generated by the [`make_federated data` function](https://github.com/tensorflow/federated/blob/master/tensorflow_federated/python/examples/remote_execution/remote_executor_example.py#L53).

Client data can be supplied in the form of a serializable `tf.data.Dataset` or, depending on how you're defining your iterative process, you can `tff.federated_map` some input data (such as client IDs) to datasets using TensorFlow.

Note that RemoteExecutors are not designed to run against data "on clients", that is, on the remote executor itself. They could perhaps be used this way using TensorFlow code to read data from the remote executor's filesystem into a dataset, but in general this is not a supported use-case. The recommended way to handle client data is to have a TensorFlow computation that can generate a `tf.data.Dataset` representing the client data based on a client ID or other input to the client's TensorFlow computation.